# Using nested loops in bash to replace characters in a string with an array of words

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, bioinformatics

I've been picking up Bash lately and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around nested loops.

Here's what I got.

```
input='ATAATAATAATG'
CODONTABLE=(ATA I ATC I ATT I ATG M ACA T
            ACC T ACG T ACT T AAC N AAT N
            AAA K AAG K AGC S AGT S AGA R
            AGG R CTA L CTC L CTG L CTT L
            CCA P CCC P CCG P CCT P CAC H
            CAT H CAA Q CAG Q CGA R CGC R
            CGG R CGT R GTA V GTC V GTG V
            GTT V GCA A GCC A GCG A GCT A
            GAC D GAT D GAA E GAG E GGA G
            GGC G GGG G GGT G TCA S TCC S
            TCG S TCT S TTC F TTT F TTA L
            TTG L TAC Y TAT Y TAA _ TAG _
            TGC C TGT C TGA _ TGG W)


for ((i=0;i<${#input};i++)) ; do
  let w+=1
  for c in $input ; do
    for h in $CODONTABLE ; do
      if [ $(echo ${input:x:3})=$(echo $CODONTABLE[w]) ] ; then
      mod+=(${CODONTABLE[w]})
      let x+=1
      else
      let w+=1
      fi
    done
  done
done
echo $mod
echo $input
```

What I get from this is...

```
ATAATAATAATG
I
```

So it seems that at least ATA was properly translated into an I.
However, what I want is

```
**ATA**ATAATAATG -> I
A**TAA**TAATAATG -> _
AT**AAT**AATAATG -> N
ATA**ATA**ATAATG -> I
```

So that the final output reads `I_NI_NI_NM`, which I use later.

In short, how do I create a proper repeating loop that goes through my input, translates every possible 3 character frame, and appends this to another array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a lot of problems with your code. Some of them are pure logic errors; others are due to misunderstandings about what various Bash constructs do. (Though I'm guessing that some of the pure logic errors are due to trial-and-error attempts to fix problems caused by misunderstandings about what various Bash constructs do.) So as a general suggestion, I'd suggest writing and testing small pieces, to see how they work, and using debugging output (small statements like `echo "i=$i w=$w c=$c h=$h"` that help you see what's going in your code). That will help you build up to a working program.

Below are a few specific problems. They are not a complete list.

---

This:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#input};i++)) ; do
  let w+=1
  ...
done
```

will give `w` the values `1`, `2`, `3`, … `12`. But I think you actually want `w` to take the values `0`, `3`, `6`, `9`? For that, you should write:

```
for (( w = 0 ; w < ${#input} ; w += 3)) ; do
  ...
done
```

(I apologize if I've misunderstood what `w` is supposed to be. Its name is not very mnemonic, and you seem to use it a few different ways, so it's hard to be sure. Incidentally — I recommend putting some effort into naming your variables better. It makes code *so* much easier to understand and debug.)

---

Since `$input` does not contain any whitespace, this:

```
  for c in $input ; do
    ...
  done
```

is equivalent to this:

```
  c=$input
  ...
```

(Maybe you were expecting `for c in $input` to loop over the characters of `$input`? But that's not what that notation does.)

---

You seem to be trying to treat `CODONTABLE` as an associative array, but you haven't written it to be one. If you're using a version of Bash that supports associative arrays, then you should use a real one:

```
declare -A CODONTABLE=([ATA]=I [ATC]=I [ATT]=I [ATG]=M [ACA]=T
                       [ACC]=T [ACG]=T [ACT]=T [AAC]=N [AAT]=N
                       [AAA]=K [AAG]=K [AGC]=S [AGT]=S [AGA]=R
                       [AGG]=R [CTA]=L [CTC]=L [CTG]=L [CTT]=L
                       [CCA]=P [CCC]=P [CCG]=P [CCT]=P [CAC]=H
                       [CAT]=H [CAA]=Q [CAG]=Q [CGA]=R [CGC]=R
                       [CGG]=R [CGT]=R [GTA]=V [GTC]=V [GTG]=V
                       [GTT]=V [GCA]=A [GCC]=A [GCG]=A [GCT]=A
                       [GAC]=D [GAT]=D [GAA]=E [GAG]=E [GGA]=G
                       [GGC]=G [GGG]=G [GGT]=G [TCA]=S [TCC]=S
                       [TCG]=S [TCT]=S [TTC]=F [TTT]=F [TTA]=L
                       [TTG]=L [TAC]=Y [TAT]=Y [TAA]=_ [TAG]=_
                       [TGC]=C [TGT]=C [TGA]=_ [TGG]=W)
```

If not, then your regular-array approach is fine, but rather than trying to use a deeply-nested loop to find the right mapping in `CODONTABLE`, you should put that logic in its own function:

```
function dna_codon_to_amino ($) {
  local dna_codon="$1"
  local i
  for (( i = 0 ; i < ${CODONTABLE[@]} ; i += 2 )) ; do
    if [[ "$dna_codon" = "${CODONTABLE[i]}" ]] ; then
      echo "${CODONTABLE[i+1]}"
      return
    fi
  done

  # whoops, didn't find anything. print a warning to standard error,
  # return the amino acid '@', and indicate non-success:
  echo "Warning: invalid DNA codon: '$dna_codon'" >&2
  echo '@'
  return 1
}
```

Then you can call it by writing something like:

```
amino_codon="$(dna_codon_to_amino "$dna_codon")"
```

Comment: Wow! Such a treasuretrove of good advice. Astounded by your help. Your assumptions about my mistakes are correct, and after going through your advice carefully I was able to find many things I had misunderstood previously about bash scripting.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of good in [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26575440/15168), but there isn't an explanation of how to step through the string 3 letters at a time, I think.  This code does that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash-4.3

declare -A CODONTABLE
CODONTABLE=(
            [ATA]=I [ATC]=I [ATT]=I [ATG]=M [ACA]=T
            [ACC]=T [ACG]=T [ACT]=T [AAC]=N [AAT]=N
            [AAA]=K [AAG]=K [AGC]=S [AGT]=S [AGA]=R
            [AGG]=R [CTA]=L [CTC]=L [CTG]=L [CTT]=L
            [CCA]=P [CCC]=P [CCG]=P [CCT]=P [CAC]=H
            [CAT]=H [CAA]=Q [CAG]=Q [CGA]=R [CGC]=R
            [CGG]=R [CGT]=R [GTA]=V [GTC]=V [GTG]=V
            [GTT]=V [GCA]=A [GCC]=A [GCG]=A [GCT]=A
            [GAC]=D [GAT]=D [GAA]=E [GAG]=E [GGA]=G
            [GGC]=G [GGG]=G [GGT]=G [TCA]=S [TCC]=S
            [TCG]=S [TCT]=S [TTC]=F [TTT]=F [TTA]=L
            [TTG]=L [TAC]=Y [TAT]=Y [TAA]=_ [TAG]=_
            [TGC]=C [TGT]=C [TGA]=_ [TGG]=W
)

input='ATAATAATAATG'
i=("AAAAACAAGAATACAACCACGACTAGAAGCAGGAGTATAATCATGATT"
   "CAACACCAGCATCCACCCCCGCCTCGACGCCGGCGTCTACTCCTGCTT"
   "GAAGACGAGGATGCAGCCGCGGCTGGAGGCGGGGGTGTAGTCGTGGTT"
   "TAATACTAGTATTCATCCTCGTCTTGATGCTGGTGTTTATTCTTGTTT"
  )

for string in "$input" "${i[@]}" 
do
    echo "$string"
    fmt=$(printf "  %%-%ds  %%3s  %%s\\\\n" ${#string})
    #echo "$fmt"
    output=""
    while [ ${#string} -ge 3 ]
    do
        codon=${string:0:3}
        output="$output${CODONTABLE[$codon]}"
        printf "$fmt" "$string" "$codon" "$output"
        string=${string#?}
    done
done
```

The key parts are the associative array and the two expressions:

```
codon=${string:0:3}  # Extract 3 characters from offset 0 of string
string=${string#?}   # Drop the first character from string
```

The first part of the output is:

```
ATAATAATAATG
  ATAATAATAATG  ATA  I
  TAATAATAATG   TAA  I_
  AATAATAATG    AAT  I_N
  ATAATAATG     ATA  I_NI
  TAATAATG      TAA  I_NI_
  AATAATG       AAT  I_NI_N
  ATAATG        ATA  I_NI_NI
  TAATG         TAA  I_NI_NI_
  AATG          AAT  I_NI_NI_N
  ATG           ATG  I_NI_NI_NM
```

Comment: This is a very useful exposition to me, as I can see in practical terms what is happening with every cycle of the program. I accept both your and Ruakh's awnser as solutions to my question, but I can't tick the box on both.

Comment: You can't accept both.  Accept Ruakh's; mine is derivative.